# Retain annotations

Tags: java, annotations, byte-buddy

I am trying to proxy methods annotated with the `RPC` annotation, which works fine, except that the annotation is removed after changing the method. This is my code:

```java
    private static Class<? extends Actor> wrapClass(Class<? extends Actor> clazz, World world) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        return new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(clazz)
            .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(RPC.class))
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodProxy.class))
            .make()
            .load(clazz.getClassLoader())
            .getLoaded();
    }
    
    public static class MethodProxy {
        @RuntimeType
        public static void proxy(@This Actor actor, @Origin Method rpcFunc, @AllArguments Object[] allArguments, @SuperCall Callable<?> zuper) throws Exception {
            RPC rpcMeta = rpcFunc.getAnnotation(RPC.class);

            // process...
        }
    }
```

Notice that the call to get the annotation here is successful - That part works perfectly.

My problem is trying to find methods annotated with `RPC` outside of the ByteBuddy stuff - Checking the list of methods of the class ByteBuddy generated using Reflection and searching for `@RPC` annotated methods in there returns no results, but if I remove the `.method` and `.intercept` in the `wrapClass` method, it works again.
Is there a way to intercept a method without removing its annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `MethodAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedMethod` via the `attribute` method:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(clazz)
  .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(RPC.class))
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodProxy.class))
  .attribute(MethodAttributeAppender.ForInstrumentedMethod.INSTANCE)
  .make()
  .load(clazz.getClassLoader())
  .getLoaded();
```